# Popover editable text

Tags: objective-c, xcode, popover

I started to make a Mac App for my Notes-Website. This app is based on a popover from the menu bar. Inside the popover I have a text field, but it's not editable although it is activated. Pasting with right click for example works... How can I make this popover interactive? Currently only the error sound of mac os plays when I press a key.

Thanks for help!

```
Code:
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    active = false;
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] 
                  statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    [statusItem setTitle:[NSString 
                          stringWithString:@"test"]]; 
    [statusItem setEnabled:YES];
    [statusItem setToolTip:@"test"];

    [statusItem setAction:@selector(StatusClicked:)];
    [statusItem setTarget:self];
}
- (void)StatusClicked:(id)sender {
    if(!active) {
        [[self popover] showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxYEdge];
        active = true;
    }
    else {
        [popover close];
        active = false;
    }
}
```

The view contains a simple multiple line-text NSTextField.

If it's not possible with a popover, are there any other possibilities of realizing this? Which elements are e.g. FaceTab (Facebook for menu bar) using, because there text fields are editable.

Comment: There shouldn't be anything special you have to do to make it interactive.  You'll need to give us some more information about how you made the popover and its view.

Comment: Okay, I changed the question and added the code.

Comment: This seems like a bug to me.  It would be interesting to see if anyone else has seen this behavior.  I copied your code into a test project I had with a popover (with button,popup button and text field).  The popover and all its controls worked properly when attached to my window, but the text field showed the behavior you described when the popover was attached to the status bar item -- the other controls worked fine.

Comment: Yes controls (buttons) within the popover are working fine.
I just want to create a Menu bar app which shows a list or a text field for taking notes. It should be like the popover, are there any other possibilities of realizing this? Which elements are e.g. FaceTab (Facebook for menu bar) using, because there text fields are editable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're making a "agent" App, with no other UI than the StatusItem. You probably have set the `LSUIElement` flag in Info.plist. (Basically, it allows to create an app without a menubar).

It also has important consequences to how the "frontmost app" and "key window" react. In your "statusClicked" method, you might want to add :

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

so that your app is really activated.

(Of course, all my comment is irrelevant if you're not writing an LSUIElement/agent Application.)

Comment: Yes, LSUIElement was activated. I deactivated it and added your code, but it is still not working :( Is "agent" a different option or something to activate/deactivate (because you said LSUIElement/agent application)? But thanks for your answer though!

Comment: No, the LSUIElement flag makes it an "agent app". Although, Apple does not use these terms very consistently.